# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'dropit' of null

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, magento

I am trying to put a jquery dropdown for "My Account" in the header after you login (try username test and password test@123) but I keep getting this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'dropit' of null

I even moved:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
$('#myaccountmenu').dropit();
});
</script>
```

to the bottom before the footer, to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there an element #myaccountmenu on your page?

Comment: @user As Jessica asked, make sure the element actually exists. The # denotes an element with the id="myaccountmenu" attribute, it can't be the class.

Comment: Is `dropit` a `jQuery` plugin? I ask because if you call `jQuery.noConflict()`it is most likely because you have another library on the page that uses `$` as shorthand. If `dropit` is a jQuery plugin then you need to write `jQuery('#myaccountmenu').dropit();` because `$` refers to another library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly**, you are calling [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/), which releases references to the global `$` variable. You will have to use `jQuery` or another variable to access the jQuery object.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
        jQuery('#myaccountmenu').dropit();
    });
</script>
```

**Secondly**, I looked at the page you are working on, and did a search and there was no element with the ID `"myaccountmenu"`. Either you have the wrong ID or the element must be generated dynamically somewhere else. If that is the case, you need to be sure that your code runs after the element is created.

Answer (score 0):

Now i had time to look at your page.
As already mentioned in my comment, you have another library (*prototype*) loaded on your page that uses `$`.
Because *prototype*  is loaded before jQuery version where you call `noConflict` on, `$` is restored to *prototype*.

So you need to change it to `jQuery('#myaccountmenu').dropit();`

But only changing this will not get your code running, you will then get an error `dropit is not defined` because you load two jQuery versions.
One before *prototype* (the 1.8.0 version) where the plugin is registered to, and then later the `1.9.1` (which you actually load twice). This will overwrite the `1.8.0` version where the plugin was registered to.

Using different libraries can result in memory leaks. Loading jQuery (even if it is the same version) multiple can also result in memory leaks and also in unexpected behavior (events that will not propagated correctly, ...)